# R Shiny/R Markdown: render() fails inside downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, pandoc, tufte

I have an RMarkdown template, `template.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Template"
output: tufte_handout
params:
    data: !r data.frame()
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Title

## Another Title

```{r echo=FALSE}
ggplot(data = params$data, mapping = aes(x=params$data$X, y=params$data$Y)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

Then I have this R Shiny app, `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 11:20)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(
  width = 6,
  actionButton("actionButton", "PDF"),
  downloadButton("downloadButton", "PDF")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$actionButton, {
    renderedFile <- render(
      input = "template.Rmd",
      output_format = "tufte::tufte_handout",
      params = list(data = data),
      output_file = "output.pdf"
    )
    browseURL(renderedFile)


  })
  output$downloadButton <-
    downloadHandler(filename <- "output.pdf",
                    content <-
                      function(file) {
                        renderedFile <- render(
                          input = "template.Rmd",
                          output_format = "tufte::tufte_handout",
                          params = list(data = data),
                          output_file = "output.pdf"
                        )
                        file.copy(renderedFile, file)
                      })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There's one `actionButton` and one `downloadButton`. They both are supposed to do the same, more or less: render a PDF (a Tufte handout, to be precise), and open respectively download it. While `browseURL` works great when I run the example on my machine, I need the `downloadHandler` when running the app in a "real" server.

The `actionButton` works perfectly, but the `downloadButton` fails:

```
"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS template.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc7146d9cfc5.pdf --template "C:\Users\paedubucher\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\tufte\rmarkdown\templates\tufte_handout\resources\tufte-handout.tex" --highlight-style pygments --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "documentclass:tufte-handout" 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> C:\temp 
                   \RtmpAtAlbM \file 714614f62c3_files
l.78 ...62c3_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS template.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc7146d9cfc5.pdf --template "C:\Users\paedubucher\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\tufte\rmarkdown\templates\tufte_handout\resources\tufte-handout.tex" --highlight-style pygments --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "documentclass:tufte-handout"' had status 43
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Stack trace (innermost first):
    53: pandoc_convert
    52: convert
    51: render
    50: download$func [C:\Users\paedubucher\Documents\R\pdf-download/app.R#28]
     1: runApp
Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

EDIT: Now there's the proper error message. Pandoc fails (Error 43), but everything works fine when it is run inside the `actionButton` context.

Comment: Hm, where would I have a factor? My data is numeric: `data <- data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = 11:20)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I messed up the code when removing the `output` constant... I'll fix it!

Comment: it's okay.  I didn't test your code. Was commenting based on the error.  Sorry for the noise

Comment: Weird, when I change the filename inside the `downloadHandler` to `"foo.bar"`, it works without any error message, but downloads a `LaTeX` file instead. The `pandoc` call has the flag `--to latex`, which should be `--to pdf`, in my opinion. But it's the same call for the `actionButton` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The friendly R Shiny folks on GitHub [pointed out the problem](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1831). `output_file` is not supposed to be used in that way. It's just the intermediate LaTeX file. The location of the PDF file is returned from `render`. This file just needs to be moved to the place the `file` parameter is pointing to:

```
  output$downloadButton <-
    downloadHandler(
      filename = "output.pdf",
      content =
        function(file) {
          output <- render(
            input = "template.Rmd",
            output_format = "tufte::tufte_handout",
            params = list(data = data)
          )
          file.copy(output, file)
        }
    )
```