# Get correct input value to display in download file name with rmarkdown word doc from downloadHandler in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have built a Shiny app and my client wants to be able to download some of its content to a Word document. Using the steps laid out [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html) (with a correction to the sample code per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147037/in-a-shiny-app-is-there-a-reason-downloadhandler-cant-render-a-pdf-from-rmark)), I have a working download button. Instead of a generic default file name like "report.docx", I want to generate a standard file name that includes the name of the subject of the report, as selected from an input value selection from a dropdown list in the UI of the Shiny app. This seems like it should be pretty easy, and I get very close: I can get the file name to include the default value for that input selection, but I can't get it to update correctly when the user makes a new selection.

The following code is a simplified example of what I want and generates the issue I am experiencing:

Data:

```
cities <- c("Atlanta", "Boston", "Chicago", "Detroit")

values <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)

test_df <- cbind.data.frame(cities, values)

saveRDS(test_df, file = "C:/Repos/Test Report Name/app/test_df.rds")
```

UI:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(reactable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput('test',
                  label = 'Test',
                  choices = sort(unique(test_df$cities)),
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selected = sort(unique(test_df$cities))[1])
            ),
    fluidRow(
      reactableOutput("data")
            ),
    fluidRow(
      downloadButton("report", "Generate Report")
    )
          )
              )
```

Server:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)
library(shinyWidgets)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$data <- renderReactable({
    
    x <- test_df %>%
      dplyr::filter(cities %in% input$test)
    
    reactable(x) 
    
  })
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = paste(input$test, "Summary", Sys.Date(), ".docx"),   ### This paste function is the crucial part; I get the default value (Atlanta) no matter which option I select. 
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(selection = input$test)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      output <- rmarkdown::render(input = tempReport,
                                  params = params,
                                  envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
      file.copy(output, file)
      
    }
  )
  
  
}
```

Markdown file:

````
---
title: "`r params$selection` Report"
output: word_document
params:
  selection: NA
---

```{r}

library(tidyverse)

x <- test_df %>%
      filter(cities %in% params$selection)

print(x)


```
````

So, I run this, and everything works, except for the file name. I select Boston in the dropdown, and I get markdown file with Boston in the title and Boston data in the table, but the file is still called "Atlanta Summary 1-3-2023.docx". I have tried creating new variables in the server file that just take the `input$test` value, such as below:

```
print_input_name <- reactive({

x <- input$test

x      
  })

## Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

 print_input_name <- eventReactive({
    
    x <- input$test
    
    x
    
  })

## Error in is_quosure(expr) : argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

I tried wrapping all that downloadHandler() statement in `observeEvent(input$test, {...})` but that didn't work either. I also tried just naming the object after the input directly (`x <- input$test`) and naming the object output$x, but that didn't work either. Also trying calling it `params$selection` like it is in the RMD file but that obviously didn't work. So I'm stumped about how to get that input selection to be stored as an object in the server that I can reference. Any help appreciated, I am pretty new to Shiny and am still learning the ins and outs of reactive elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (`?downloadHandler`) the `filename` argument should be

> A string of the filename, [...]; or *a function that returns such a string*. (**Reactive values and functions may be used from this function.**)

Hence to fix your issue use

```
filename = function() paste(input$test, "Summary", Sys.Date(), ".docx")
```

See also the examples section of the docs.

Complete reproducible code:

```r
cities <- c("Atlanta", "Boston", "Chicago", "Detroit")
values <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
test_df <- data.frame(cities, values)

library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      selectInput("test",
        label = "Test",
        choices = sort(unique(test_df$cities)),
        multiple = FALSE,
        selected = sort(unique(test_df$cities))[1]
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      reactableOutput("data")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      downloadButton("report", "Generate Report")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$data <- renderReactable({
    x <- test_df %>%
      dplyr::filter(cities %in% input$test)

    reactable(x)
  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste(input$test, "Summary", Sys.Date(), ".docx"),
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      params <- list(selection = input$test)
      output <- rmarkdown::render(
        input = tempReport,
        params = params,
        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
      file.copy(output, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3354
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick and clear answer!!! Works perfectly. I swear I'm not so lazy I didn't check the ?downloadHandler help, I just misunderstood and thought "or a function" meant I was okay to use paste(), I didn't realize I had to add that function() at the start.